# Two properties change when I clicked on a button with AMP.setState. AMP-BIND

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

I have this code on AMP:

```
<style amp-custom>

  .plus, .mius {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .plus {background-color: blue;}
  .mius {background-color: green;}

  .visible {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:block;
  }

  .no-visible {
    display: none;
  }

</style>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
<body>
  <amp-state id="text">
   <script type="application/json">
   {
      "textspan1": "plus",
      "textspan2": "visible"
   }
   </script>
  </amp-state>

     <p [text]="textspan1=='plus'?'mius':'plus'" [class]="textspan1=='plus'?'mius':'plus'" class="plus"></p>

      <button on="tap:AMP.setState({textspan1: (textspan1 == 'plus' ? 'mius' : 'plus')})">pulsar</button>

    <p [class]="textspan2=='no-visible'?'visible':'no-visible'" class="plus"></p>
    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({textspan2: (textspan2 == 'visible' ? 'no-visible':'visible')})">pulsa visible</button>

 </body>
</head>

</html>
```

When i clicked on a button (i don't mind the clicked button) execute the two states of them. Only i want is click on a button and i execute one state, no two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169583/conditionally-hide-or-show-inputs-amp I think this is what you need.